# Confused about syntax when using for loop to add to array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I recently came across the following piece of sample code:

```
function range(upto) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= upto; i++) {
    result[i] = i;
  }
  return result;
}
```

and I'm confused as to why:

```
result[i] = i;
```

as opposed to:

```
i = result[i];
```

Isn't 'i' the variable and 'result[i]' the value?

Comment: No, `result[i]` is the variable and `i` is the value it is being set to. The purpose of that line of code is to set the variable `result[i]` to the value `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `result[i] = i;` means you are assigning the value of `i` to the index `i` of the array `result`.
- `i = result[i];` means you are assigning the value of the `i-th` index of the array `result`,to the variable `i`.

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

This fills the array :

```
result[0] = 0 // sets the first cell of the array to the value 0
result[1] = 1
etc.
```

This function returns

```
[0, 1, 2, ... upto]
```

[More about arrays in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 1):

The

```
result[i] = i;
```

assigns the value of `i` to the `i`-th element of `result`.

Thus, `result[0]` becomes `0`, `result[1]` becomes `1` and so on.